# on click event won't fire after AJAX filter manipulates the DOM

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on an e-commerce site that have AJAX filter that manipulates the dom based on each product attributes.

I am writing another AJAX call to pull more product attributes on each product on click.

[Here is the link to the dev site](http://dev.thisiswhatiwant.com)

Here is my AJAX call

```
$('.each-product').on('click', function (e) {

    /** Prevent Default Behaviour */
    e.preventDefault();

    /** Get Post ID */
    var post_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var response_class = '.' + post_id + '-ajax-response';


    /** Ajax Call */
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: { action: 'product_extra_info', id: post_id },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(response_class).show().html("Loading...");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(response_class).show().html(data);
            //alert(data);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You should bind click event to those dynamically created DOM elements. (Those created by lazy load)

Comment: Any errors showing up in the Console?

Comment: Use event delegation. Go read the documentation on jQuery’s `.on` to see how that works.

Comment: @vrej please post your jQuery function code that you are using for defining on click function that being called after ajax filter..

Answer (score 0):

See [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event delegation. With `click` you can't bind to things that are dynamically added to the DOM. Switching your code to use `on` would look like:

```
$('.products').on('click', '.each-product', function (e) {

    /** Prevent Default Behaviour */
    e.preventDefault();

    /** Get Post ID */
    var post_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var response_class = '.' + post_id + '-ajax-response';


    /** Ajax Call */
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: { action: 'product_extra_info', id: post_id },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(response_class).show().html("Loading...");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(response_class).show().html(data);
            //alert(data);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```